# Call customer navigation on homepage MAGENTO 2

Tags: magento2

how I can call customer navigation on the homepage in Magento 2?

I tried to do it on default.xml, but it does not work, is it possible?

And if I do it with that code, another menu on the custom extension will add to that menu? Like the menu showing on the customer view

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">nav items</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Delimiter" name="customer-account-navigation-delimiter-1" template="Magento_Customer::account/navigation-delimiter.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address Book</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/address</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">190</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Information</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/edit</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">180</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Delimiter" name="customer-account-navigation-delimiter-2" template="Magento_Customer::account/navigation-delimiter.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create customer_account.xml file in your theme or module. The path of this file is given below.

If you want to add a link in your module, then the path should be

> app/code///view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

If you want to add a link in your theme, then the path should be

> app/design///Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

Now, we need to create customer_account.xml at the respective paths given above. Add the following code in the file just created.
https://pastebin.com/0RKe5iED